# How to count and show item from one column SQL?

Tags: mysql

In table data store in different column. One Column is **url** in which I store **repeating value** and one column for **title**. I want to show **individual title count against each value of URL**.
Data in Table is
[enter image description here][1]

and I want something like that
[enter image description here][2]

> but data in above image is not correct I need each speaker contain how
> many apple count, google count etc in same line.

I tried code below but it is not producing required output.

```
select 
id, 
user_id as "User Id", 
title as "Speaker Name",
page_url as "Page URL",
app_id as "App Id",
created_at,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Apple' THEN 1 END) AS Apple,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Google (online)' THEN 1 END) AS Google,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Yahoo (online)' THEN 1 END) AS Yahoo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Office 365 (online)' THEN 1 END) AS 'Office 365',
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Outlook' THEN 1 END) AS 'Outlook',
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Outlook.com (online)' THEN 1 END) AS 'Outlook.com (online)'
FROM vepdb.click_tracking AS u where u.app_id=10000076 group by url,title;
```

and also tried piece of code

```
select 
id, 
user_id as "User Id", 
title as "Speaker Name",
page_url as "Page URL",
app_id as "App Id",
created_at,
sum(case when url = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) as Apple,
sum(case when url = 'Google (online)' then 1 else 0 end) as Google,
sum(case when url = "Yahoo (online)" then 1 else 0 end) as Yahoo,
sum(case when url = 'Office 365 (online)' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Office 365',
sum(case when url = 'Outlook' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Outlook', 
sum(case when url = 'Outlook.com (online)' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Outlook.com (online)' 
FROM vepdb.click_tracking AS u where u.app_id=10000076 group by url,title;
```

How can we produce this output. Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ab2n.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um0vn.png

Comment: Provide a sample ( table structure as textual code-formatted `CREATE TABLE`, some data as `INSERT INTO`, desired output for this data ) and precise MySQL version (complete output for `SHOW VERSION();`). You may simplify sample data (remove excess columns), but check that the scripts are correct and adequate.

Comment: Your codes cannot work correctly. They contains incomplete grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. I have solve it. I have to r**emove url from group** by its work fine

```
select 
id, 
user_id as "User Id", 
title as "Speaker Name",
page_url as "Page URL",
app_id as "App Id",
created_at,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Apple' THEN 1 END) AS Apple,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Google (online)' THEN 1 END) AS Google,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Yahoo (online)' THEN 1 END) AS Yahoo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Office 365 (online)' THEN 1 END) AS 'Office 365',
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Outlook' THEN 1 END) AS 'Outlook',
COUNT(CASE WHEN url='Outlook.com (online)' THEN 1 END) AS 'Outlook.com (online)'
FROM vepdb.click_tracking AS u where u.app_id=10000076 group by title;
```